# Can I automatically delete a file when opening a program?

Tags: windows-7, automation

I would like to automatically delete a specific file (a cache file) whenever I open the game *World of Warcraft*. How would I accomplish this? Is this something that be done with a shortcut? Do I have to write a *.bat file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may create shortcut, for batch file (.bat or .cmd does not matter)

for Example (RunGame.cmd)

```
del "FullPathToYourCacheFile"
start "" "FullPathToGameExecutable"
```

You may add specific game args after `"FullPathToGameExecutable"` if the game needs them.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this can be done. Even without a batch file.

Create a shortcut and supply the following command as location:

```
cmd /c del "PathToCacheFile" & start "" "PathToGameExecutable"
```

To avoid seeing a command prompt popping up, right-click the shortcut, select `Properties` change `Run: Normal window` to `Run: Minimized`.

Comment: While I like the idea of not making a batch file when I don't need to, I am currently using Steam to launch my game so I can't avoid the command prompt with shortcut properties.

Comment: I bet you could achieve that too, but it's probably not worth the effort. I wouldn't have posted a second answer, if you didn't specifically ask if it was possible without a batch file.

Comment: Sorry. You did get my upvote though, so it wasn't in vain! :D

Comment: No worries. A batch file *is* the proper way to do this. I just didn't want to leave that part unanswered.